# Group values in one label in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I have a field which is named: **grupo** it contains this values: Repairs & Maintenance . . . a lot of values I want to choose just the important thing and group all the other in autres: Other and calculate the total.

[image]

How can I do that in qlikview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can advise you to make this in the script - create new field in the same table where `grupo` field is. The new field should be based on `mapping` table or something like this: `if( match( grupo, 'ICMS','PENALTY' ) > 0, grupo, 'Other') as grupo1`